# Container not taking remaining screen height

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this widget called `TopRoundedContainer` and I created it like this:

```
return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: color,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
      topRight: Radius.circular(40),
    ),
  ),
  child: child,
);
```

I'm using it in this screen where it's get called and built inside `Body()` widget like this :

```
    class _ProductDetailState extends State<ProductDetail> {
  //int activeSize = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF5F6F9),
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
        child: CustomAppBar(),
      ),
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
    Widget Body() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          //Container for image .. ,
          TopRoundedContainer(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.name as String,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(25),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            height: 1.5),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal:
                                        getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Product description :",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: getProportionateScreenHeight(15),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                            child: Text(
                              widget.description as String,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(14),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                        child: Text(
                          "Price : " + widget.price.toString() + "\$",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(23),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: getProportionateScreenHeight(45),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                            child: Text(
                              "Disponible",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(16),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  height: 1.5),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                            child: Text(
                              "Sur Commande",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.orange,
                                  fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(16),
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  height: 1.5),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: SizeConfig.screenWidth * 0.8,
                        child: DefaultButton(
                          text: "Add to the cart",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

The problem is , as you can see there is a blank grey space at the end(after add to cart button). I want to make `TopRoundedContainer` takes the the remaining screen height after the `ImageContainer` .

How can I achieve that ?

Thank you .

Comment: "left" is ambiguous; I assume you mean "left over" or "remaining"...?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe : yes sorry , I'm not an english native speaker. I edited the title.

Comment: Hey Before where you have displayed this ` Price: 120$ ` widget add spacer() like this instead of sizedBox(), do not had any properties inside space() method.